# Can a circuit with three-ways be split in two branches?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, multiway-switch, canada

I have a circuit like this:

```
panel ======= three-way (1) ============ three-way (2) ===== ceiling-mounted fixture
```

I would like to have another fixture a bit further, with its own new three-way, but retain the first three way:

```
panel ======= three-way (1) ============ three-way (2) ===== ceiling-mounted fixtureA
                               ||
                               ========= three-way (3) ===== ceiling-mounted fixtureB
```

So, fixtureA would be switched on/off by (1) and (2) and fixtureB would be switched on/off by (1) and (3). Assume all necessary wires have the 2 needed travellers. I know how to wire it.

I realize the usability issue: switching (1) could turn (2) on and (3) off. That's OK.

My question is there any electrical code issues I'd be facing ? Any security concerns I may have missed ? Location is Canada, QC.

Comment: other than you you cant branch wires between junction boxes I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some inspectors will give you a hard time over that usability issue. Three-ways are required in certain hallways and stairways, and an inspector who doesn't know when a three-way is required and when it isn't, might simply reject anything that confuses him.

You can purchase a single yoke device with two three-ways, that physically occupies one gang location in a switch box.. Perhaps you could wire your circuits like this:

```
             three-way (1a) ===== three-way (2) ===== ceiling-mounted fixture A
panel =====<<
             three-way (1b) ===== three-way (3) ===== ceiling-mounted fixture B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that *if you really, really want to*, using common 3-way switches and simply pigtailing the two travelers and neutral at switch 1 or switch 2.

I recommend splitting the branches at switch 1, so that when you regain your senses, you can simply get a twin 3-way switch and fall back to the solution A. I. Breveleri recommends.